# How to upload program .exe with raylib.h library so user could use it without downloading raylib directly?

Tags: c++, exe, raylib

***How to upload program .exe with raylib.h library so user could use it without downloading raylib directly?***
I made a game using raylib.h
now I want to send a game to my friend so he could play but he can't open it if I just send .exe file(he don't have raylib instaled). **Is here a way to send it so he could just download the game file and play it?**
Game do not use some textures or external files except raylib.h.
Hope I explained clearly enough ;)

Comment: statically link all needed libraries

Comment: If your program didn't use anything external except "raylib.h", there wouldn't be a problem, since that file is used only during compilation.

Comment: *"with raylib.h library"* -- Is the library called "raylib.h" or "raylib"? A library name ending in ".h" suggests a header-only library, which would be necessarily become part of your executable during the compilation phase. A library that you need to link against (which might have a **part** that is a `.h` *file*) might be different.

Answer (score -1):

Create an installer (.MSI on Windows) that packages your app + all its dependencies (don't forget the compiler runtime libraries). Then send the .MSI to your friend to install.